# How is it possible to get killed by the Green Slime?

Tags: achievements, crypt-of-the-necrodancer

In the full release of CotN, there is an achievement where you have to get killed by a green slime.

This mob doesn't move. despite his non-null attack value , he can't possibly harm the player, because in order to attack, a mob must move towards the player.

Of course, there must be a way, else the game shouldn't have that achievement.

Any tips?

Comment: I (or somebody else) will have to test this, but my first guess would be bounce traps. http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Traps Unless the bounce counts as you attacking the enemy.

Comment: I was wrong. Seems you need to get exceedingly creative with this one. Green slimes simply do not do any damage. Not if you bounce against them. Not if you run into them without even a weapon.

Comment: The bounce traps or the arrow traps add an additionnal move to the entity stepping on it, however, only the ennemies can use this extra move to strike, the player doesn't use his weapon if there is an ennemy or a box. I have read some files about the caracteristics of the mobs, and the green slimes have an attack attribute different from zero, but since `attack = move on the same square as the target`, we have to use some very special setup to make him move.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're going to need to be quite creative with this one, but it can be done.
The good news is, if you manage to get a green slmie to hurt you, it seems to do a lot of damage. At least **5** hearts worth.

Here's the setup and explanation:

> First of, you need a way to make the green slime move. Almost no enemy can hurt you, unless *they move into you*. Scroll of Fear will make the slime move without hurthing it.
> Secondly, you need to move to have the slime move towards you. There are a couple of ways to do this.
>  **Scenario A: Confuse**
>  When the slime gets confused, it will move in the opposite directions. This means, in stead of moving away from you (under the Fear effect), it moves *towards* you. There are a couple of ways to cause confuse
>  [image: Scroll of Fear and Dove]
>  The most reliable way to get a slime confused, is to play *Dove* (unlocked by beating Zone 2.) Her weapon is the Flower that causes Confuse on all the enemies hit. Of course, playing Dove makes finding the Scroll of Fear less likely, as shops will only carry two items instead of three.
>  [image: Scroll of Fear and a Confuse Trap]
> Alternatively, you need a Confuse Trap. The Feared Slime will need to move onto this trap at which point it will swiftly change direction and berge right into you. *(May not be viable as Confuse Traps and Green Slimes don't seem to spawn on same floors.)*
>
> With all this done, you only need to stand still and let the green, slimy nature take its course.
>
>  **Scenario B: Bounces (highly unlikely)**
>  [image: Scroll of Fear and Bounce Traps]
>  If you're really lucky, you'll find the bounce traps in a configuration that will bounce the frightened slime on you. These may be rather rare, tough, as you need the slime to bounce one square *behind* its original position.

I've tested this in the level editor mode and these both work reliably. However, it seems you can't get the achievement this way. You'll just have to play the game normaly and hope to get what you need.

<strike>Who knows, maybe someone will find a seed that will have these setups easily attainable.</strike> [According to the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/247080/discussions/0/618460171322088825/#c618460171329389076), you can't unlock achievements with seeded runs.

Comment: I can't remember seeing confusing traps in Zone 1. Do they spawn there now ?

Comment: @Anton Bounce traps might work?

Comment: @Studoku You are absolutely right. Just tested that an with a right setup it will.

Comment: What about local co-op ? One uses the scroll and the other gets killed ! And you don't need setup with that... just a friend.

Comment: Found a better way to get the other half of the problem solved. Added it into the answer.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help. (Also, I added my solution with the co-op)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the possibilities described by DJ Pirtu, I have found another way.

> The AI of the green slime is very simple : do not move.
> To make him move, we have to teach him an AI, which is doable by using the **scroll of fear**, I don't think there is any other way to alter an ennemy's AI.
> If a green slime move to you, he proceeds to hit you, like any other mob. Fortunately, he has enough strength to kill a 5-hearted player (to be tested with 10 hearts equipped with the full-armored set).
>
> Based on that, you can use **local co-op**.
> Put the two players in each side of a green slime.
>  **`P1 Slime P2`**
>
>  One of the players use the scroll of fear, and the green slime will flee him, causing him to run on the other player and instant-kill him, leaving the other player alone.

I don't know if it unlocks the achievement, (I already did thanks to DJ Pirtu) but at least, the green slime killed my character.

Answer (score 3):

Use local co-op: one player chooses Eli, the other can pick anyone.

Use Eli to shove (he shoves instead of attacks) the slime into the friend. Green slimes do 50 damage so unless you have a DLC quartz armor (reduce all damage to 1) it's instant death.

Comment: By far the best answer here.  No need to even get a friend - shouldn't take long to do it yourself given it's a stationary enemy in the first level.

Answer (score 1):

Playing as dove might make things a lil easier, hit the slime to confuse it, fear scroll right after, it should bump right into you instead of running away

Comment: Thank you, but that's exactly what DJ Pirtu told me in his answer. So you're not adding new *informative* material.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on Playstation's Forum:

Mostly Harmless Trophy
"It can be done through a seeded run with Dove. If your on vita before use 2074892, and on PS4 the seed will be 2074891." (there are seeds all over the place for PC)

I've tried this, and yes, I received the trophy.